# can i use jsoup for html to xml transformation?

Tags: java, html, xml, transformation, jsoup

i am new in java. Now i am doing a project related to content transformation.
i have used jsoup for link extraction from web page. Now i want to know can i use same jsoup for transform html  to xml. Could you please answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSoup to extract links . once you will have those links you can either use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) or [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to serialize them to XML file.

Comment: Hi Joshi,i went through JAXB. But it is saying about xml to dom processing.But i want how to converthtml to xml. I aso tried JTidy. But it gives well formatted html as output. How can i make xml for dom processing. please help me for this....

Comment: ya.. i got something as converter in xstream now iam going through that.... Thank you..

Comment: Thank you very much joshi.. I got answer.